# mySQL query to target different keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query that returns the user's top published posts in post_status `publish`.

Looks like this:

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
   SELECT      tt.term_id as category, COUNT(p.ID) as count
   FROM        $wpdb->posts p

   JOIN        $wpdb->term_relationships tr
               ON p.ID = tr.object_id

   JOIN        $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt
               ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
               AND (tt.taxonomy = %s AND tt.term_taxonomy_id != 1)

   WHERE       p.post_author = %s and p.post_status = 'publish'
   GROUP BY    tt.term_id
   ORDER BY    count DESC LIMIT 3
",
    $taxonomy,
    $user_id
) );
```

It checks for the `post_author` ID and checks if `post_status` is `publish`. Works fine. However, I want to find posts from `post_status` `publish` and `active`.

I tried setting `WHERE` to:

```
p.post_author = %s and p.post_status = 'publish' or p.post_status = 'active'
```

But this returned all `active` posts, not **specifically** this user's.

How can I change my query so it targets both `publish` and `active` for this user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use parenthesis like this

```
p.post_author = %s and (p.post_status = 'publish' or p.post_status = 'active')
```